# Rotate an object in unity for a cardboard app

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, google-cardboard

I have a car object which has to be rotated when the player head of the cardboard moves. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to hack the CardboardHead.cs class attached to the Head GameObject in the CardboardMain prefab. This is what is handling the rotation based on the Gyro & Accelerometer.

Basically:

- apply the rotation to CardboardMain, the parent of Head, and not the Head GameObject itself
- offset the Head in the negative Z axis
- disable track position